# Is there any automatic way of adding directives in all my existing files of my angular project?

Tags: angular, project

Suppose I have to add a `directive` called `bidi` in all my `matInput` fields .And I have approx 1000 input fields in 250 files in my project.
Is there any way to automate this process instead of manually doing it?
Thanks.

Comment: The directive has to be imported into every module it is used in, the cli will only add it to the nearest ngModule. If you have a shared kernel you could add it there and save yourself the hassle of adding it to each and every module it is needed in. Furthermore, you can set the selector of the directive to something like `[matInput]`, which means it gets added to every element with this attribute automatically

Comment: I'm sorry but my question was how to add directive in ```html``` file automatically with some kind of script or something,```[matInput]``` way might work but I need to add it some other type of input fields too,like ```mat select``` or ```mat-radio```,

Answer (score 0):

You can use your ide's functionality.

If you are using visual studio code you can use the shortcut `ctrl + shift + h` to find all `<input matInput ... >` tags and replace them with `<input matInput bidi ...>` (this is an example, search what you have written in your code).
Otherwise all IDEs have search and replace function, so try it out: it's much simpler than writing a bash script or something like that.

Given the number of tags you want to modify be careful to watch for errors.

Comment: Yes,I've tried that,but its little more complex, since there are multiple people working in this, in some places its ```<input matInput type="text' ...> ``` or ```<input type="text" matInput...>```  or  ```<input class="custom-ip" type="text" matInput...>```

Comment: @AbuTaha Many IDE's support regex search and replace. It's a little more complex I agree, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replace the content with regex as @Federico Andreoli mentioned in his comment.

In visual studio code try to press `ctrl+shift+h` and enable the gear icon next to the input box to enable the regex mode

[image]

And use the following pattern in your search area

```
(<input[^>]+matInput)([^>]*>)
```

And use the following string in your Replace Area

```
$1 bidi$2
```

So finally it looks like the below image

[image]

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XD9m0d/2/)